# how to wait for some other event to complete before returning value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have one HttpClient service, which takes cares of all rest calls. 
Now, before making rest call I want to load a iframe and then continue the same function call.

```
public get(url, searchParams: URLSearchParams =  new URLSearchParams(), headers: Headers = new Headers() ) {
  if (some condition) {
    let iframe = this.createIframe();
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
        resolve(this.doGET(url, this.getOptions(searchParams, headers))); 
    }, this.time_delay));
  } else {
    return this.doGET(url, this.getOptions(searchParams, headers));
  }
}
```

Here is createIframe method :

```
private createIframe() {
    let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    this.createSomeUrl('').then(function (url) {
         iframe.src = url;
    });
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    return iframe;
 }
```

Here, I am making `doGet()` call wait for some time by using `setTimeout`, but it does not gives guaranty that `iframe` is finish its work.

There is one variable which gets updated when `iframe` finish its work, I can know that `iframe` is finished its work by checking that variable, But by that time how to stop get method wait to return promise?

Comment: Using $timeout function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

```
private checkSomeConditions(): Promise {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        if (some condition) {
            let iframe = this.createIframe();

            // Assuming the iframe is closing after the job is done
            iframe.onbeforeunload( _ => {
               console.log('iframe is closing');
               resolve();
            });
        } else resolve();
    });
}

public get(url, searchParams: URLSearchParams =  new URLSearchParams(), headers: Headers = new Headers() ) {
    return this.checkSomeConditions()
    .then( _ -> {
        return this.doGET(url, this.getOptions(searchParams, headers);
    })
    [...]
}
```

Comment: When you answer SO questions you should explain what you are doing rather than just posting bare code. That is more likely to help the questioner understand for the future.

Comment: Alexis thanks for your help, but here I am trying to avoid using time out, I want to be sure that iframe has finished its work before making doGet call.

Comment: Wooops. Completely misread your question, sorry for that. Instead of using timeout, you could listen to events occuring on iframe, depending on your need (Ex : iframe.onload = function() { // Loaded  }; ). Assuming that the iframe closes itself after the job is done, you can listen for 'onbeforeunload' too. Editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Observables, this can be easily done using `flatMap()`:

```
public get(url, searchParams: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(), headers: Headers = new Headers()) {
    if (somecondition) {
        let iframe = this.createIframe();

        return Observable
            .delay(this.time_delay)
            .flatMap(() => {
                iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
                return this.doGET(url, this.getOptions(searchParams, headers));
            })
    }
    else {
        return this.doGET(url, this.getOptions(searchParams, headers));
    }
}
```

Now, when you subscribe to your `.get()` method, it will delay if `someCondition` is true, or return otherwise.

Comment: thanks for your help, but here I am trying to avoid using time delay, I want to be sure that iframe has finished its work before making doGet call.